# Why is Sequelizer is ignoring my username

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have a NestJS project I have set up and am trying to use Sequelizer to access my database.  Currently, I have a database provider and module set up to be used globally (the module is injected in my app.module) that are set up as follows:

database.module.ts:

```
import {Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { databaseProvider } from './database.provider'

@Global()
@Module({
 providers: [databaseProvider],
 exports: [databaseProvider]
})
export class DatabaseModule{}
```

database.provider.ts:

```
import {Sequelize } from 'sequelize-typescript';

export const databaseProvider = {
  provide: 'SequelizeInstance',
  useFactory: async () => {
    const config = {
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
      logging: false,
      dialect: 'mssql',
      force: false,
      timezone: '-07:00'
    };

    const sequelize = new Sequelize(config);
    return sequelize;
  }
};
```

My module to call the code uses a module and service that is setup as follows:

db.module.ts:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DBService } from './db.service';
import { DBController } from './db.controller'

@Module({
  controllers: [DBController],
  providers: [DBService],
  exports: [DBService]
})
export class DBModule {}
```

db.service.ts:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class DBService {
  constructor(
    @Inject('SequelizeInstance') private readonly sequelizeInstance
  ) {}

  public async getRegions(): Promise<any> {
    return this.sequelizeInstance.query('EXEC pr_region_lst')
    .then(data => data)
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

The problem I am having is that sequelizer keeps throwing an error that the Login failed for user ''.  I attached a debugger and am looking at the code in the db.service.ts.  When I look at sequelizeInstance, it shows the config having the username from the configuration file I provided.  I don't know why it is not using it in the DB context though.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my issue.  It seems that the 'tedious' package was not installed on my project.  The msssql package however was.  So it was apparently not using the driver correctly to connect to the database.  Once I added tedious, the connection started working.